# Oscillation of a Function at the Endpoint of an Interval

Tags: real-analysis

If $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is some function, $I \subseteq [a,b]$ some interval, and $x \in [a,b]$, then $I_{\delta, x} := (x- \delta,x+\delta) \cap [a,b]$, $\omega_f(I) := \sup_{x,y \in I} |f(x)-f(y)|$ and $\omega_f(x) := \inf_{\delta > 0} \omega_f(I_{\delta,x})$.

> Problem: If $a \in G := \{x \in [a,b] \mid \omega_f(x) < t \}$, then there is some $r > 0$ such that $[a,a+r) \subseteq G$.

Attempt: Because $a \in G$, it follows that $\omega_f(a) < t$ and so there is some $r > 0$ such that $\omega_f(I_{r,a}) < t$. I claim that $[a,a +r/2) \subseteq G$. Let $z \in [a,a+r/2)$. If $x,y \in I_{r/2,z}$, then $|z-x| < r/2$ and $|z-y| < r/2$. By the triangle inequality,

$$|x-a| \le |z-x| + |z-a| < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2} =  r,$$

so that $x \in I_{r,a}$. Similarly, $y \in I_{r,a}$. Again, by the triangle inequality,

$$|x-y| \le |z-x| + |z-y| < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2} = r.$$

Therefore $|f(x)-f(y)| \le \sup_{x,y \in I_{r,a}} |f(x)-f(y)| < t$. Since $x,y \in I_{r/2,z}$ were arbitrary, it follows that $\sup_{x,y \in I_{r/2,z}} |f(x)-f(y)| \le t$ or $\omega_{f}(I_{r/2,z}) \le t$, so that $\omega_{f}(z) \le t$...

As you may notice, quantity of interest is less than ***or equal*** to $t$; but I need strict inequality in order to conclude $z \in G$.  I know I need to slip $\frac{t}{2}$ in somewhere, but I don't see where this can be done. I could use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \sup_{x,y \in I_{r,a}} |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \omega_f(I_{r,a})$. First take sup over $x$ and $y$ and then use the fact that $\omega_f(I_{r,a})<t$.